# Heterogeneous type of items in one master-child relationship

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

Probably this has been asked before, but couldn't find a good answer: I have a master table that could be in 1-to-many relationship with of heterogeneous entities. Best to describe it with an example:

I have master table of audio playlist (tb_playlist). The playlist could contain program episodes (tb_episode), songs (tb_songs) or audio reportage (tb_reportae). The straightforward design which I know is not best for data integrity would be like this:

```
**tb_playlist** 
(
playlist_id,
audioitem_id [can be episode_id, song_id, reportage_id],
audioitem_type [can be: episode, song, or reportage]
)
```

The above solution clearly doesn't enforce data integrity, the alternate might be null columns as follows:

```
**tb_playlist** 
(
playlist_id,
episode_id, 
song_id, 
reportage_id
)
```

but the later is bad for expanding audio item types.

The question is what is the best way to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create an entity-relationship diagram of the problem. I understand you've got a hierarchy there: A **PlayList** can have many **PlayListItems**. There are three kinds of **PlayListItems** (here is where I see the hierarchy): **Episodes**, **Songs** and **Reportages**.

Check this question to see how to handle hierarchies: [What is the best database schema to support values that are only appropriate to specific rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685621/what-is-the-best-database-schema-to-support-values-that-are-only-appropriate-to)

Comment: I am not able to upload images as I am new to stackoverflow. Your understanding is correct. Playlist can have multiple items, each item can be a foreign key from a different table (Songs, episodes and reportages). Each table of the three tables is a separate entity that has its own attributes.

Comment: I am afraid I could not get the right answer from your post. I know there are cons and pros for each solution. I want to keep all tables without any killing (I've had enough of killing all around the world). So my questions: should I go for single column for the item_id along with item_type, or should i go for nullable foreign keys.. or is there even a better solution that doesn't include any killing...