# Modeling database with 2 type of users (web and twitter)

Tags: mysql, database, types, entity-relationship

I have two types of users on the database:
-Web registered users
-Twitter users

I have to store data of both:
- Web registered users: id, nick, mail, verified, password
- Twitter users: id, nick

Currently i have just 2 tables:
- webUsers: **id**, nick, mail, verified, password
- twitterUsers: **id**, nick

But it carry some problems for example with the comments table. Both users can make comments so i would need two foreigns key and that's not possible.

I also thought about this possibility:
- users: **id**, nick
- users_twitter: **id**, 
- users_web: **id**, nick, mail, verified, password.

It would represent the main table **users** with two childrens: **users_twitter** and **users_web**.
But... the table **users_twitter** has only one field: **id** isn't that weird?

What would you recommend me?
OH, by the way. Twitter users id is the one i get from twitter API, so it might be possible that ID could be same of my of the web users ID.

Thanks.

Comment: do you care at runtime which type of user it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you've a hierarchy there. You have some common fields that could be part of a `Users` table and some others that should be part of each of the childrens: `UsersTwitter` and `UsersWeb`. You can take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685621/what-is-the-best-database-schema-to-support-values-that-are-only-appropriate-to/9460541#9460541) to see how to handle hierarchies.

Comment: I am just wondering if creating a whole table just for a duplicate field "id" would be right or not.

But thinking about it. Maybe it would be a better idea to create 2 id's for twitter users. The autoincrement ID i have on my users table and then the twitter Id. 
So now my twitter_users table would have: id, twitterId

Would it be correct? THanks!!

Comment: This is not named "hierarchy". It's the supertype/subtype pattern. Hierarchies are something different.