# Table inheritance in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

Seems like a basic question but it is very important to decide how it should be. Here is the scenario

I have a table "ABC" and other table "Category"

ABC contains the basic information which is common among all the Vendors
ABC will have the CategoryID in it
Then I have a table named ABCCatA (this table has specific information which is not common to all the tables). Similarly I will have table ABCCatB (having specific field)

Or can I just use table ABC and add all the fields (even specific fields) in the same table to avoid joins and one table for each category?

How can I model this structure in relational DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heavily depends on kind and size of data you're expecting to be dealing with, especially when considering performance.

Also, this question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1125145/2729170