# SQLITE : how many columns in a table

Tags: sqlite, join

I designed an sqlite database with 2 tables. I did this because i tought that it's not recommanded to insert many columns in a single table. in table 1 I have more than 40 columns, and in table 2 +10 columns
Now, when i use the database, i have to do an INNER JOIN to find all fields from the 2 tables.

My question is :
Is it better to perform a join between the 2 tables, or create only one table with all the fields (at the end, more than 60) ?

This second option will save an INNER JOIN, so i guess this will speed up the query

Comment: What do you need those 50 columns for?

Comment: it store one to one data. I'm using it to create an html table "searchable" from it table. as i split the data into 2 tables, i have to do a join

Answer (score 1):

It is better to create different tables because it is easily maintainable as well as it is a good practice. Similar answer you can find
[Here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125004/which-is-more-efficient-multiple-mysql-tables-or-one-large-table?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: thanks for this link, very interesting. I have a 1to1 relation between tables, according to your links, there is no benefits spliting the datas. what about performance (speed)?