# Single table or multiple table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am developing a stock market analysing web application. I have to store  more over 20 years of data of 2000 company's with 150+ columns.
   My doubt is whether I have to create separate table for each company or single table. Which is faster.

Answer (score 0):

before create database or decision you should design database with some tips and tricks.

i can't describe here cause of there are lots of points and tricks available.

that why i add link below for reference. you should read and implement as your requirement.

https://www.dummies.com/programming/web-services/exploring-database-design-tips/

https://www.vertabelo.com/blog/notes-from-the-lab/9-tips-for-better-database-design

> Note :- don't use ready made database related your requirement
>   do your self to improve your database decision.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends generally. But most of the times in industry they follow normalization structure. My suggestion would be don't create each table for each company. Make a table for all the companies. Store their details in seperate tables. Try to make your tables to follow 1:1 relationship. So that you can easily get results. See below links please. If you want more performance make another table with only those columns which are very important.(You said 150 columns i don't think all of them are useful.)

[Which is more efficient: Multiple MySQL tables or one large table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125004/which-is-more-efficient-multiple-mysql-tables-or-one-large-table)